# Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, linux

I am having trouble compiling and running my Java code, intended to allow me to interface Java with a shared object for Vensim, a simulation modeling package.

The following code compiles without error:

```
javac -d . -cp ./apache-log4j-1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar:./vensim.jar SpatialModel.java     VensimHelper.java VensimException.java VensimContextRepository.java
```

However, when I try to run the following:

```
java -cp ./apache-log4j-1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar:./vensim.jar SpatialModel vars
```

I get the following error: "Error: Could not find or load main class SpatialModel
".  My SpatialModel.java code does contain a 'main' method (below), so I'm not sure what the problem is - can anyone please help me out?  Thanks.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class SpatialModel {

    private VensimHelper vh;

    public static final String DLL_LIBNAME_PARAM = "vensim_lib_nam";

    public static final String MODEL_PATH_PARAM = "vensim_model_path";

    private final static int VENSIM_CONTEXT_CREATION_MAX_FAILURE_COUNT = 10;

    public SpatialModel() throws SpatialException {

        String libName = System.getProperty(DLL_LIBNAME_PARAM);
        String modelPath = System.getProperty(MODEL_PATH_PARAM);        

        if(libName == null || libName.trim().equals("")) {
            log.error("Vensim library name has to be set with -D" + DLL_LIBNAME_PARAM);
            throw new SpatialException("Vensim library name has to be set with -D" + DLL_LIBNAME_PARAM);
        }

        if(modelPath == null || modelPath.trim().equals("")) {
            log.error("Model path has to set with -D" + MODEL_PATH_PARAM);
            throw new SpatialException("Model path ahs to be set with -D" + MODEL_PATH_PARAM);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < VENSIM_CONTEXT_CREATION_MAX_FAILURE_COUNT && vh == null; i++) {
            try {
                log.info("creating new vensim helper\n\tdll lib: " + libName + "\n\tmodel path: " + modelPath);
                vh = new VensimHelper(libName, modelPath);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                log.error("An exception was thrown when initializing Vensim, try: " + i, e);
            }
        }
        if (vh == null) {
            throw new SpatialException("Can't initialize Vensim");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws VensimException {

        long before = System.currentTimeMillis();   
        String libName = System.getProperty(DLL_LIBNAME_PARAM);
        String modelPath = System.getProperty(MODEL_PATH_PARAM);

        if (libName == null) {
            libName = "libvensim";
        }
        if(modelPath == null) {
            modelPath = "~/BassModel.vmf";
        }

        System.setProperty(DLL_LIBNAME_PARAM, libName);
        System.setProperty(MODEL_PATH_PARAM, modelPath);

        if (args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("info")) {
            System.out.println(new VensimHelper(libName, modelPath).getVensimInfo());
        } else if (args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("vars")) {
            VensimHelper helper = new VensimHelper(libName, modelPath);
            String[] vars = helper.getVariables();
            for (String var : vars) {
                System.out.println(helper.getVariableInfo(var));
            }
        } else {

            File f = new File(".");
            System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());

            SpatialModel sm = new SpatialModel();
        }

        System.out.println("Execution time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - before));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 300, accepted):

You must ensure that you add the location of your `.class` file to your classpath. So, if its in the current folder, add `.` to your classpath.
Note that the Windows classpath separator is a semi-colon, i.e. a `;`.

Comment: And if someone didn't notice in the question the classpath separator in Linux is a colon `:`.

Comment: @JavierMr Thanks for pointing out classpath separator in Linux. I ended up using this: `javac -cp third_party_lib.jar MyClass.java` and for execute: `java -cp .:./third_party_lib.jar MyClass` (notice the dot **.** and colon **:** after -cp option)

Comment: See This one too..    http://stackoverflow.com/a/6069764/565661

Comment: how to do this in STS with same error?

Comment: This error occurs when you write wrongly the name of the main method or you use the package statement without putting the class in the correct folder structure.

Comment: @Saket "You must ensure that you add the location of your .class file to your classpath. "
How to add location of our .class to our class path in eclipse ide?

Comment: I know you're supposed to avoid comments like "ugh", but that's exactly how I feel about this.  I'm using a colon in my classpath and the engine isn't complaining at all about an illegal classpath!  It just says "Could not find or load main class".  I searched for that error when I realized I must be doing something stupid.  Thank you!

Comment: In Windows, using a batch to run your Java may only cause this error if passing an argument of a file from a parent folder. Having the batch first cd to the same directory as the Java file will fix it.

Answer (score 151):

If the class is in a package

```
package thepackagename;

public class TheClassName {
  public static final void main(String[] cmd_lineParams)  {
     System.out.println("Hello World!");
  } 
}
```

Then calling:

```
java -classpath . TheClassName
```

results in `Error: Could not find or load main class TheClassName`. This is because it must be called with its fully-qualified name:

```
java -classpath . thepackagename.TheClassName
```

And this `thepackagename` directory must exist in the classpath. In this example, `.`, meaning the current directory, is the entirety of classpath. Therefore this particular example must be called from the directory in which `thepackagename` exists.

To be clear, the name of this class is not `TheClassName`, It's `thepackagename.TheClassName`. Attempting to execute `TheClassName` does not work, because *no class having that name exists*. Not on the current classpath anyway.

Finally, note that the compiled (*.class) version is executed, not the source code (*.java) version. Hence “CLASSPATH.”

Comment: And this command must be called from the directory in which the thepackagename directory exists.  Easy to miss but VERY important.

Comment: @aliteralmind your answer worked for me as my class was inside a package. Can you please explain why it needs to be done this way if the class is inside a package?

Comment: Thank you! Mine Stupid mistake of package name.

Comment: This was my problem. Totally non-obvious for someone coming from a non-java background.

Comment: Very concise and helpful, thanks.

Comment: Thanks this saved lots of my time. This is why I always feel Kafkaesque in Java

Answer (score 68):

You can try these two when you are getting the error: 'could not find or load main class'

If your class file is saved in following directory with `HelloWorld` program name
`d:\sample`

1. `java -cp d:\sample HelloWorld`
2. `java -cp . HelloWorld`

Comment: This works great. But why please?

Comment: it works because it tells the java interpreter where the bytecode class files are.

Comment: That's the simplest answer I think. Thanks!

Answer (score 39):

I believe you need to add the current directory to the Java classpath

```
java -cp .:./apache-log4j-1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar:./vensim.jar SpatialModel vars
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My life was saved! After previous editing of CLASSPATH. Current directory was no longer in CLASSPATH. That's why I keep getting "could not find or load main class" and "could not find symbol" when they are right in the current directory. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: For those with the same problem, here's how to add the current directory to CLASSPATH  `shell$ export CLASSPATH=.:$CLASSPATH`

Comment: This is clearly what has to be done, but according to the Java documentation it should not be needed. Here's what the Oracle java docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html say "The default value of the class path is ".", meaning that only the current directory is searched"

Comment: @S.N. - You are misinterpreting.  That is the >>default<< value for the classpath.   If you supply an explicit classpath via `$CLASSPATH` or `-cp` or any other way, then the default classpath is not relevant.  The OP is using `-cp`.

Comment: @StephenC: of course, I had a brain misfire when I wrote that!

Answer (score 36):

You have to include classpath to your javac and java commands

```
javac -cp . PackageName/*.java
java -cp . PackageName/ClassName_Having_main
```

suppose you have the following

Package Named: com.test
Class Name: Hello (Having main)
file is located inside "src/com/test/Hello.java"

from outside directory:

```
$ cd src
$ javac -cp . com/test/*.java
$ java -cp . com/test/Hello
```

- In windows the same thing will be working too, I already tried

Comment: Clear explanation and working on Windows 10

Answer (score 32):

If you work in Eclipse, just make a cleanup (`project\clean..` `clean all projects`) of the project.

Answer (score 20):

You have to set the classpath if you get the error:

> Could not find or load main class XYZ

For example:

```
E:\>set path="c:\programfiles\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin"
E:\>set classpath=%classpath%;.;
E:\>javac XYZ.java
E:\>java XYZ
```

Answer (score 20):

I got this error because I was trying to run

```
javac HelloWorld.java && java HelloWorld.class
```

when I should have removed `.class`:

```
javac HelloWorld.java && java HelloWorld
```

Comment: Could not find or load main class mainClass

Comment: Glad none of my coworkers saw me trying to figure this out for half an hour

Answer (score 12):

Check your `BuildPath`, it could be that you are referencing a library that does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 10):

If you're getting this error and you are **using Maven to build your Jars**, then there is a good chance that you simply do not have your Java classes in `src/main/java/`.

In my case I created my project in Eclipse which defaults to `src` (rather than `src/main/java/`.

So I ended up with something like `mypackage.morepackage.myclass` and a directory structure looking like `src/mypackage/morepackage/myclass`, which inherently has nothing wrong. But when you run `mvn clean install` it will look for `src/main/java/mypackage/morepackage/myclass`. It will not find the class but it won't error either. So it will successfully build and you when you run your outputted Jar the result is:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class mypackage.morepackage.myclass
```

Because it simply never included your class in the packaged Jar.

Comment: so what is the fix for the problem. I am getting the error because of the Maven

Comment: @BaradwajAryasomayajula the fix is to move your Java class files into the `src/main/java/` directory, because that's where Maven expects them to be.

Comment: I have added class under src/main/java/ and it is also there in generated jar but I am still getting same error while running the jar :(

Answer (score 9):

I know this question was tagged with linux, but on *windows*, you might need to separate your cp args with a `;` instead of a `:`.

`java -cp ./apache-log4j-1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar;./vensim.jar SpatialModel vars`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Answer (score 8):

If you try to run a java application which needs JDK 1.6 and you are trying to run on JDK 1.4, you will come across this error. In general, trying to run a Java application on old JRE may fail. Try installing new JRE/JDK.

Answer (score 6):

Problem is not about your main function. Check out for

```
javac -d . -cp ./apache-log4j-1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar:./vensim.jar SpatialModel.java     VensimHelper.java VensimException.java VensimContextRepository.java
```

output and run it.

Answer (score 6):

I was using Java 1.8, and this error suddenly occurred when I pressed "Build and clean" in NetBeans. I switched for a brief moment to 1.7 again, clicked OK, re-opened properties and switched back to 1.8, and everything worked perfectly.

I hope I can help someone out with this, as these errors can be quite time-consuming.

Answer (score 6):

Project > Clean and then make sure BuildPath > Libraries has the correct Library.

Answer (score 6):

`java -verbose:class HelloWorld` might help you understand which classes are being loaded.

Also, as mentioned before, remember to call the full qualified name (i.e. include package).

Answer (score 5):

This problem occurred for me when I imported an existing project into eclipse. What happens is it copied all the files not in the package, but outside the package. Hence, when I tried run > run configurations, it couldn't find the main method because it was not in the package. All I did was copy the files into the package and Eclipse was then able to detect the main method. So ultimately make sure that Eclipse can find your main method, by making sure that your java files are in the right package.

Answer (score 5):

If so simple than many people think, me included :)

cd to **`Project Folder/src/package`** there you should see yourClass.java then run **`javac yourClass.java`** which will create yourClass.class then cd out of the *`src`* folder and into the *`build`* folder there you can run **`java package.youClass`**

I am using the Terminal on Mac or you can accomplish the same task using Command Prompt on windows

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Eclipse... I renamed my main class file and got that error.  I went to "Run As" configurator and under the class path for that project, it had listed both files in the class path.  I removed old class that I renamed and left the class that had the new name and it compiled and ran just fine.

Answer (score 2):

This solved the issue for me today:

```
cd /path/to/project
cd build
rm -r classes
```

Then clean&build it and run the individual files you need.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem in Windows, it's related to the classpath. From the command line, navigate until the directory where it's located your Java file (*.java and *.class), then try again with your commands.

Answer (score 2):

I use Anypoint Studio (an Eclipse based IDE). In my case everything worked well, until I found out that while running the java code, something totally different is executed. Then I have deleted the .class files. After this point I got the error message from this question's title. Cleaning the project didn't solve the problem.

After restarting the IDE everything worked well again.