# What's missing from this jar build?

Tags: java, netbeans-7

Alright, here's what's confusing me:

I've been messing around with some simple coding using Netbeans to compile and run some java programs, now that I've gotten a hang of it, I tried building a jar file and opening it outside of Netbeans, but I was smacked in the face by this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class C:\Users\n\Desktop\DirectoryLi
st_1\DirectoryList_1\build\classes\directorylist\DirectoryList_1.jar
```

What I'm unsure of is how/why this is happening as I can run the program, which produces a textfile with some info in it, completely fine when I'm running it in Netbeans, what's being excluded? What went wrong?

Here's the log from compiling the jar:

Thanks for the help!

```
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: C:\Users\n\Desktop\DirectoryList_1\DirectoryList_1\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\Users\n\Desktop\DirectoryList_1\DirectoryList_1\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\n\Desktop\DirectoryList_1\DirectoryList_1\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\Maxunknown\Desktop\DirectoryList_1\DirectoryList_1\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: C:\Users\n\Desktop\DirectoryList_1\DirectoryList_1\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\n\Desktop\DirectoryList_1\DirectoryList_1\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\n\Desktop\DirectoryList_1\DirectoryList_1\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\n\Desktop\DirectoryList_1\DirectoryList_1\build\classes
compile:
Created dir: C:\Users\n\Desktop\DirectoryList_1\DirectoryList_1\dist
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\n\Desktop\DirectoryList_1\DirectoryList_1\build
Nothing to copy.
Building jar: C:\Users\n\Desktop\DirectoryList_1\DirectoryList_1\dist\DirectoryList_1.jar
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "C:\Users\n\Desktop\DirectoryList_1\DirectoryList_1\dist\DirectoryList_1.jar"
jar:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

The very messy and should probably be better organized code:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package directorylist;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * This program lists the files in a directory specified by the user. The user
 * is asked to type in a directory name. If the name entered by the user is not
 * a directory, a message is printed and the program ends.
 */
public class DirectoryList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
//            String directoryName;             // Directory name entered by the user.
//            Scanner scanner;                  // scanner reads from standard input.
//            scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // scanner reads from standard input.
//
//            System.out.print("Enter a directory name: ");
//            directoryName = scanner.nextLine().trim();

            String indent = "";
            String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
            String fileSeparator = System.getProperty("file.separator");

            File log = new File(userHome + fileSeparator + "log.txt");
            FileOutputStream stream;
            stream = new FileOutputStream(log);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(stream);

//            System.out.println(userHome);
//            System.out.println(fileSeparator);

            for (int i = 0; i < userHome.length(); i++) {
                if (userHome.charAt(i) == fileSeparator.charAt(0)) {
                    userHome = userHome.substring(0, i + 1);
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Files in directory \"" + userHome + "\"");
            out.println("Files in directory \"" + userHome + "\"");
            directoryListV2(userHome, 1, out);
        } // end main()
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DirectoryList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } // end main()

    public static void directoryListV2(String directoryName, int directoryLevel, PrintWriter out) {

        File directory;        // File object referring to the directory.
        String[] files;        // Array of file names in the directory.
        directory = new File(directoryName);
        String fileSeparator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
        String indent = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < directoryLevel; i++) {
            indent += "  ";
        }

        if (directory.isDirectory() == false) {
            if (directory.exists() == false) {
                System.out.println("There is no such directory!");
                out.println("There is no such directory!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("That file is not a directory.");
                out.println("That file is not a directory.");
            }
        } else {
            files = directory.list();
//            System.out.println("Files in directory \"" + directory + "\":");
//            out.println("Files in directory \"" + directory + "\":");

            if (files != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    if (isDirectory(directoryName + fileSeparator + files[i] + fileSeparator)) {
                        System.out.println(indent + directoryName + fileSeparator + files[i] + fileSeparator);
                        out.println(indent + directoryName + fileSeparator + files[i] + fileSeparator);

                        directoryListV2(directoryName + fileSeparator + files[i], directoryLevel + 1, out);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(indent + files[i]);
                        out.println(indent + files[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        out.flush();
    }

    private static boolean isDirectory(String directoryName) {
        File directory;

        directory = new File(directoryName);
        if (directory.isDirectory() == true) {
            if (directory.exists() == true) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
} // end class DirectoryList
```

Comment: The main class declaration in the manifest, probably.

Comment: Already asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class

Comment: How did you try to run the jar? What does the MANIFEST.MF look like?

Comment: That's even more confusing, the manifest is there, with the contents :

Manifest-Version: 1.0
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build

Comment: I tried to run the jar file simply by clicking on it, then by typing the full path name of the jar file in the CMD, producing that error message

Comment: So from what I understand, jar files cannot be used by none programming people? What's the correct way to build a program for their use then?

Comment: Did you try java -jar "C:\Users\n\Desktop\DirectoryList_1\DirectoryList_1\dist\DirectoryList_1.jar"

Comment: Yes, I tried that, the code runs in the CMD but no file is produced, I was trying to make a file that any normal person could use, are jar files the right way to go?

Comment: Definitely, in fact if everything is set up correctly, you can double click the jar file to run it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the main class in you jar is not loaded.

For that you will have to make a menifest entry for the Main Class in the jar.

You can find best tutorial on creating executable jar [here](http://csdl.ics.hawaii.edu/~johnson/613f99/modules/04/jar-files.html)

Other resource can also found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html.3) which is Sun's main guideline for creating executable jars.

Hope this will work for you.

Enjoy !!

Comment: Ahhhh, what you said sounds logical but I'm still being plague by the problem! I've tried a few things:

Adding Main-Class: directorylist.DirectoryList to the manifest
Doing the same thing with the full path name instead

Yet the error occurs!

Comment: Then there may be problem in you coding.

Comment: But it runs as expected while in the IDE, is that possible?

Comment: Then please copy and paste the menifest file.

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.3
Created-By: 1.7.0_03-b05 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: 
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: directorylist.DirectoryList

Comment: where is main class definition ?

Comment: Is that not the part which says Main-Class: directorylist.DirectoryList?

Comment: There is only one class in the package, the beginning of the java file looks like this:

package directorylist;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * This program lists the files in a directory specified by the user. The user
 * is asked to type in a directory name. If the name entered by the user is not
 * a directory, a message is printed and the program ends.
 */
public class DirectoryList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {