# Cannot find or load main class ERROR

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error: Could not find or load main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class)

ive been working on some game code for a few hours now and it worked perfectly fine before, but then my eclipse decided to corrupt some stuff, I recovered it fully and it works perfectly in eclipse but when I try to run it via CMD or just as an Executable JAR I get Cannot find or load main  class ERROR. Here is the current main method I have.

```
public Game() {
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * 2, HEIGHT * 2));
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * 2, HEIGHT * 2));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * 2, HEIGHT * 2));
    frame = new JFrame(NAME);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setIconImage(Icon);
}

private boolean running = false;
public InputHandler Inputs = new InputHandler(this);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Starting");
    Game g = new Game();
    g.Start();
}

public void Start() {
    running = true;
    new Thread(this).start();
}

private static final int MapHeight = 40;

public void Stop() {
    running = false;

}
```

Im using windows 7 and JAVA 7. 
Hope I can get some help.

Comment: Have you set the main class in the manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want an executable jar, you need to have a MANIFEST.MF file that defines the main class to run...

```
Main-Class: net.test.Class
```

If you want to run from the command line, you have to tell it what class to run, and probably the class path.   This could go into a .bat

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: Game Thats what in my manifest

Comment: @LucassSpencer Is it possible that your `Game` class is inside some package? If so then `Main-Class:` should contain `your.package.name.Game`.

Comment: I have just updated it and yes it is in a package, it wasnt when I put up the message here is what it says now.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse click on the project -> right click -> Export.
Select Runnable Jar file.

Select a Launch Configuration which worked in Eclipse.

Eclispe will generate that MANIFEST.MF file for you into your jar file.

then oyu can run on your cmd: java -jar niceJarfile.jar and everything will work fine.

If not open the jar file and look if the right main-class is mentioned there.

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0 Class-Path: . Main-Class: Game Thats what in my manifest  yes it is

Comment: You don't have packages? Its always "save" to put your Classes into a package. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package Just try it out.

Comment: I do now , to no avail...

Comment: I did try what you siad multiple times.