# Opening .xlsx file with Apache POI gives NoClassDefFoundError InvalidFormatException

Tags: excel, ubuntu, apache-poi, noclassdeffounderror

I'm having trouble getting the import of all the required .jar files working correctly.
My end goal is simply to read in an excel spreadsheet (more specifically .xlsx files) to check whether the speed of Apache POI will work for future applications.

**My question is why am I getting thrown the error...**

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/openxml4j/exceptions/InvalidFormatException

...when I can see in the class InvalidFormatException at /org/apache/poi/openxml4j/exceptions/ in the 'file poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar'?

I haven't done programming in Java in a while and I'm hoping for my own sanity that I've made a stupid mistake. My code seems to be compiling correctly but I have the above error message when I try run the program. I have done some research into my issue but haven't been able to find someone in my situation. They usually just forget/don't have a required .jar file. Maybe I'm in the same boat but hopefully you'll be able to tell me.

I'll give a breakdown of my logic. Here is the code in TestExcel.java

```
import java.io.FileInputStream; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; 
import java.io.FileOutputStream; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.InputStream; 

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell; 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row; 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet; 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook; 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory; 

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;

public class TestExcel 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        InputStream inp; 
        try 
        { 
            inp = new FileInputStream("cost.xlsx"); 

            Workbook wb; 
            try { 
                wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp); 
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 
        } 
        catch (InvalidFormatException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
        catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Here is the file 'c_test' used to compile and run the java code:

```
javac -classpath "/home/robsco/Webdev/java/poi/*" TestExcel.java
java TestExcel
```

Here is the directory listing of the classpath above:

```
robsco@roblaptop:~/Webdev/java/poi$ ls -al
total 26616
drwxrwxr-x 2 robsco robsco     4096 Aug 18 18:13 .
drwxrwxr-x 6 robsco robsco     4096 Aug 18 18:12 ..
-rwxr-xr-- 1 robsco robsco    52915 Sep 18  2009 commons-logging-1.1.jar
-rwxr-xr-- 1 robsco robsco   313898 Apr  5  2009 dom4j-1.6.1.jar
-rwxr-xr-- 1 robsco robsco   121070 Apr  5  2009 junit-3.8.1.jar
-rwxr-xr-- 1 robsco robsco   358180 Apr  5  2009 log4j-1.2.13.jar
-rwxrw-r-- 1 robsco robsco 14841622 Aug 18 13:15 ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar
-rwxr-xr-- 1 robsco robsco  1869113 Nov 26  2012 poi-3.9-20121203.jar
-rwxr-xr-- 1 robsco robsco    30446 Nov 26  2012 poi-excelant-3.9-20121203.jar
-rwxr-xr-- 1 robsco robsco   936648 Nov 26  2012 poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar
-rwxr-xr-- 1 robsco robsco  4802621 Nov 26  2012 poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar
-rwxr-xr-- 1 robsco robsco  1226511 Nov 26  2012 poi-scratchpad-3.9-20121203.jar
-rwxr-xr-- 1 robsco robsco  2666695 Apr  5  2009 xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
```

and the output of executing 'c_test':

```
robsco@roblaptop:~/Webdev/java$ ./c_test 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/openxml4j/exceptions/InvalidFormatException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2521)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2764)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1653)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

**I am using:** 
OS: Lubuntu 12.10 x86

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)

robsco@roblaptop:~/Webdev/java/poi$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_25
```

Comment: Could you perhaps also have some older POI jars on your classpath? See [this POI FAQ Entry for how to check](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006)

Comment: Thanks for the response @Gagravarr. I tried the code on that FAQ and added an import for the POIFSFileSystem and URL classes and got this error at run-time:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/POIFSFileSystem
 at TestExcel.main(TestExcel.java:24)`

It seems strange that it can't find that class when I specifically imported it and the poi jar is on my classpath.

Comment: Your shell script appears to be passing in a classpath for the compile (javac) step, but not the run (java) step, could it be as simple as that?

Comment: That was it! Thanks @Gagravarr. I feel a bit stupid now about assuming the external jars were somehow linked at compile time. Add your comment as a response and I'll accept it.

I had to do this as well for anyone else interested to get the external libraries and my class linked at runtime: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with how you're launching your program. I see you currently have a shell script of:

```
javac -classpath "/home/robsco/Webdev/java/poi/*" TestExcel.java
java TestExcel
```

That compiles with all the jars, but doesn't run with them, so your program won't have its dependencies available. (Unlike with some c programs, compiling with Java won't inline the depdendencies, nor will it add local links to the files. There are tools that will do that for you if you really need it though)

If you change your shell script to be:

```
javac -classpath "/home/robsco/Webdev/java/poi/*" TestExcel.java
java -classpath ".:/home/robsco/Webdev/java/poi/*" TestExcel
```

It should work fine. Note the addition of the current directory in the classpath in order for 'java' to find your class (in this case TestExcel).

Alternately, you could do something a little icky with environment variables, using the `CLASSPATH` envvar that Java checks, eg

```
export CLASSPATH=.:`ls -1d --color=no /home/robsco/Webdev/java/poi/* | xargs echo | sed 's/ /\:/g'`
javac TestExcel.java
java TestExcel
```