# Program that compresses and decompresses a string in Java

Tags: java, debugging, loops, compression

I need this code to compress and decompress a string given by the user, to compress the user will type either "java compression -c" or just "java compression". To decompress, it will be "java compression -d". Any help would be appreciated. It will now compile and run; however, when you type in the string it will only print out compress and not the compressed string.

```
import java.util.*;
public class practice
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String originalString = scan.nextLine();
        String compressedString = "";
        int index = 0;
        int numReps = 0;
        char nextChar = ' ';
        if (args.length==0 || args[0].equals("-c"))
        {
            System.out.println("compress");
            String s = scan.next();
            compress(originalString);
            System.out.println(compressedString);
        }
        else if (args[0].equals("-d"))
        {
            System.out.println("decompress");
            decompress(compressedString);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error! Unknown mode.");
        }

    }

    public static void compress(String originalString)
    {
        int index = 0;
        int numReps = 0;
        char nextChar = ' ';
        while (index < originalString.length())
        {
            numReps = 0;
            char c = originalString.charAt(index);
            if (!Character.isDigit(c))
            {
                nextChar = c;
                index++;
            }
            else
            {
                while (Character.isDigit(c))
                {
                    int temp = Integer.parseInt(""+c);
                    numReps = temp;
                    index++;
                    if (index >= originalString.length()) break;
                    c = originalString.charAt(index);
                }
                for (int i =0; i<numReps; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(nextChar);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void decompress(String compressedString)
    {
        int index = 0;
        int numReps = 0;
        char nextChar = ' ';

        while (index < compressedString.length())
        {
            numReps = 0;
            char c = compressedString.charAt(index);
            if (!Character.isDigit(c))
            {
                nextChar = c;
                index++;
            }
            else
            {
                while (Character.isDigit(c))
                {
                    int temp = Integer.parseInt(""+c);
                    numReps = (numReps*10) + temp;
                    index++;
                    if (index >= compressedString.length()) break;
                    c = compressedString.charAt(index);
                }
                for (int i =0; i<numReps; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(nextChar);
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error. If yes, show us the error

Comment: BTW any reason you are ending `while` loops in your code like here `while (index < input.length());`

Comment: @Prateek That's how my tutor was telling me to do it.(He couldn't figure this out either.) Are the extra () after length not needed?

Comment: Depends on what `input` is. If it is an array then you have to use `.length` because length is a property of array; but if it is `String` then use `length()` as `length()` is a method of `String` Class

Comment: @Prateek I changed some stuff in the code, does this look better?

Comment: @Prateek It compiles now, but I get the error message listed above.

Comment: Read accepted solution to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class

Comment: (1) Don't add the `.java` extension when you're running a Java program.  (2) Spell `practice` correctly.

Comment: @Prateek I don't know what a classpath is

Comment: @gdhc Then read about it

Comment: @gdhc21 Which IDE are you using - might be time to learn about debuggers...

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten the type argument for your method definitions:

```
public static void decompress(compressedString)
```

Should be

```
public static void decompress(String compressedString)
```

Or even better

```
public static void decompress(final String compressedString)
```

Comment: What's the difference between the two? Also, can you see anything else wrong with the program?

Comment: @gdhc21 `final` declares the method parameter immutable; it's just good practice.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things going wrong in your code(As far as I can see):-

1. `public static void decompress(compressedString)` should actually be `public static void decompress(**String** compressedString)`. You have to tell the `method` that the `argument` it is going to receive is of `String` type.
2. In your `compress` and `decompress` methods you have `while (index < input.length());`. Check **;** at the end. Do you really want that. You will never execute the `while` loop because you are terminating it before it even begins.