# Mallet SimpleTagger Classpath

Tags: java, classpath, mallet

I am going to use Mallet SimpleTagger for sequence tagging. However, I have problem with setting the classpath. As I have seen here: [classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

I must be able to use java -cp to set the classpath.
I followed the instructions [here](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/sequences.php) (I am sure that I have installed Ant and Mallet correctly). However, I receive this message:

```
Error: could not find or load main class cc.mallet.fst.SimpleTagger
```

Here is the real code that I use:

```
C:\mallet> java -cp "C:\mallet\class:C:\mallet\lib\mallet-deps.jar" cc.mallet.fst.SimpleTagger --model-file G:\test1-model G:\test2-feats.txt
```

Meanwhile, when I run this command: `echo %CLASSPATH%`, it returns %CLASSPATH%.

I would be thankful if anybody can help me.

Comment: If it return `%CLASSPATH%`, it means that you have not set the classpath. Are you using any particular IDE ..? Like Eclipse or NetBeans.?

Comment: No, I am directly using the command line. However, isn't "java -cp" supposed to set the classpath?

Comment: Why is your string like `C:\mallet\class:C:\mallet\lib\mallet-deps.jar` ..? Why the two `C:`..?

Comment: Try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class

Comment: this was on the website of Mallet (as I referred in my question):
`java -cp "/home/hough/mallet/class:/home/hough/mallet/lib/mallet-deps.jar"`
As it was for linux, I tried to change it to be correct for my windows OS. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, thanks to comments and suggested link of @user2339071, I could solve the problem:

If you are using Windows OS, you must replace ":" with ";".
So, this code worked for me:

```
C:\mallet> java -cp "C:\mallet\class;C:\mallet\lib\mallet-deps.jar" cc.mallet.fst.SimpleTagger --model-file G:\test1-model G:\test2-feats.txt
```

Actually, what is done with this code is that two different paths are determined as the classpath, one is the folder which includes .class files of mallet (C:\mallet\class) and the other one includes all required jar files (C:\mallet\lib\mallet-deps.jar) and you need to separate them with ";".

That's all!