# Mallet SimpleTagger FileNotFoundException: c:\mallet-2.0.7 (Access is denied)

Tags: java, classpath, filenotfoundexception, mallet

I tried running Mallet from windows cmd following exactly the examples in the documentation and also from the solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219351/mallet-simpletagger-classpath)
I keep getting this error, what could be the problem?

```
c:\>java -cp "C:\mallet-2.0.7\class;C:\mallet-2.0.7\lib\mallet-deps.jar" cc.mallet.fst.SimpleTagger --model-file c:\mallet-2.0.7 c:\mallet-2.0.7\sample.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\mallet-2.0.7 (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at cc.mallet.fst.SimpleTagger.main(SimpleTagger.java:519)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this command instead and it works. It created a crf model file "nouncrf"

> c:>java -cp "C:\mallet-2.0.7\class;C:\mallet-2.0.7\lib\mallet-deps.jar" cc.mallet.fst.SimpleTagger --model-file nouncrf sample.txt