# Error: Could not find or load main class com.lara.CoffeeTest

Tags: java

when I am trying to run this code I am getting

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.lara.CoffeeTest

can anybody tell me the reason

```
 class Coffee {
        int size;
    }

public class CoffeeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Coffee drink= new Coffee();
        drink.size=2;
        System.out.println(drink.size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class?rq=1

Comment: check your classpath. If from command line, use `-cp` and specify the folder your class is in

Comment: Change to the directory where com directory resides and then execute java com.lara.CoffeeTest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java classpath` doesn't contain your CoffeeTest.class file.`java` adds the current directory to the classpath by default unless there is `CLASSPATH` variable defined in the environment. You can make it work by executing the following

Change to the directory  where 'com' directory resides and execute

```
//if CLASSPATH variable set in environment
java -cp . com.lara.CoffeeTest
```

or

```
java com.lara.CoffeeTest
```

provided you have compiled and .class files are present with the same package structure as that of source.