# error:could not find or load main class

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

On my ubuntu terminal i was trying to compile and run the program like this:

```
javac -cp "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_20/lib/gs-core-1.2.jar" GraphExplore.java
```

successfully compiled. Now to run

```
java -cp "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_20/lib/gs-core-1.2.jar" GraphExplore
```

I got error saying

**Error: Could not find or load main class GraphExplore**

I am newbee in java.please someone help me to resovle this issue.thanks in advance.what i tried to resolve this error. I kept .class file in one folder and run i mean i kept in one path and tried to execute in that path only but it didnt work.please help me.

Comment: please add the tag "java" to this question.

Comment: add . to the classpath

Comment: Maybe you want to try java -cp "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_20/lib/gs-core-1.2.jar" ./GraphExplore

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: Could not find or load main class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class)