# Java - could not find or load main class error

Tags: java, load, find, program-entry-point

I just added some code to a project and suddenly I get these errors.  The class in question does have a main method and the other class ClientLauncher in the client package exists.  I checked and the classes have the correct package listed in them.  Any suggestions on what I should check?  Thanks.

Error: Could not find or load main class client.ClientLauncher

selection does not contain a main type

Comment: Please show the exact method declaration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: Could not find or load main class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class) (or one of the other [linked questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/7485670?lq=1)).

Comment: I found something that might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what was going on, because I had deleted the last project and started over.  But I just got a similar error and thought I'd post this in case it helps someone.  In the process of doing a similar project, I forgot to include "String args[]" in the main method definition and only had"
public static void main().  This gave a similar "does not have main method".  The moment I added the above and had:
public static void main(Strings args[]);
then the error went away and the code ran correctly.