# PowerLoom - could not find or load main class edu.isi.powerloom.PowerLoom

Tags: java, cmd

I am trying to install PowerLoom in my windows. I have Java 1.7.0_60 and Java SE Environment 1.7.0_60-b19. By the way, when I want to make this command to create the file powerloom.bat :

```
java –cp powerloom.jar;stella.jar edu.isi.powerloom.PowerLoom
```

I have this error **could not find or load main class edu.isi.powerloom.PowerLoom**

Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: Could not find or load main class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class)

Answer (score 0):

The list passed to `java -cp` should be delimited by a colon (`:`), not a semicolon (`;`):

```
java –cp powerloom.jar:stella.jar edu.isi.powerloom.PowerLoom
```