# Java - Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, eclipse, class, program-entry-point

I am trying to run a Graphical user interface i programmed, and am encountering an error when i try to run to run my program in Eclipse. This following message is displayed in the console: " Error: Could not find or load main class". My java file is in the default package, and I have have little luck problem solving and searching on the internet. Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;



import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class myWindow implements ActionListener, MouseListener,         MouseMotionListener, ChangeListener {
    private int width, height;

    private JFrame myWindow;
    private JPanel panel1, panel2, panel3, panel4, panel5;
    private JButton button1, button2, button3;
    private JLabel label1;
    private JCheckBox checkbox1;
    private JRadioButton radiobutton1;
    private JColorChooser colorChooser;

    private boolean mousePressed;
    private int old_x, old_y;
    private Color color;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myWindow w = new myWindow();


    }

    public myWindow()
    {
        width = 600;
        height = 400;       
        mousePressed = false;
        old_x = 0;
        old_y = 0;
        color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
        myWindow = new JFrame();
        myWindow.setSize(width, height);
        myWindow.setLocation(100, 100); // Sets location of the window
        myWindow.setTitle("Window title");

        myWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    // Terminates the program on close

        button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        button3 = new JButton("Button 3");

        checkbox1 = new JCheckBox("Check"); // Creates check box
        radiobutton1 = new JRadioButton("Radio Button");    // Creates radio button

        colorChooser = new JColorChooser();

        panel1 = new JPanel();  // Creates panel
        panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel3 = new JPanel();
        panel4 = new JPanel();
        panel5 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        panel1.add(panel2); // Adds panel
        panel1.add(panel3);

        panel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel2, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));  // Changes to make buttons vertical
        panel2.add(panel4);
        panel2.add(panel5);

        panel3.add(colorChooser);

        panel4.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel4, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel4.add(button1);    // Adds button to stated panel
        panel4.add(button2);
        panel4.add(button3);
        panel4.add(checkbox1);
        panel4.add(radiobutton1);
        myWindow.add(panel1); 

        label1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("res/images/dota2.jpg")); // Gathers the image
        panel5.add(label1);


        button1.addActionListener(this);
        button2.addActionListener(this);
        button3.addActionListener(this);
        label1.addMouseListener(this);
        label1.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        colorChooser.getSelectionModel().addChangeListener(this);

        myWindow.setVisible(true);  //Makes window visible
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == button1)
        {
            System.out.println("Button 1 pressed.");
            button1.setText("Button 1 pressed");
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == button2)
        {
            System.out.println("Button 2 pressed.");
            button2.setText("Button 2 pressed");
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == button3)
        {
            System.out.println("Button 3 pressed.");
            button3.setText("Button 3 pressed");
        }

    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == label1)
        {
            System.out.println("Mouse clicked.");
            System.out.println("(x,y) = (" + e.getX() +  ", "  + e.getY()  + ")");
            Graphics g = label1.getGraphics();
            g.drawOval(e.getX(), e.getY(), 3, 3);

        }
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        System.out.println("mousePressed = " + mousePressed);
        Graphics g = label1.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(color);
        g.drawOval(e.getX(), e.getY(), 3, 3);
        mousePressed = true;
        old_x = e.getX();
        old_y = e.getY();
    }


    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("mousePressed = " + mousePressed);
        if(mousePressed)
        {
            Graphics g = label1.getGraphics();
            //  g.drawOval(e.getX(), e.getY(), 3, 3);
            g.setColor(color);
            g.drawLine(old_x, old_y, e.getX(), e.getY());
            old_x = e.getX();
            old_y = e.getY();
        }   
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        if(mousePressed)
        {
            Graphics g = label1.getGraphics();
            g.setColor(color);                              //I DID THIS MYSELF
            g.drawOval(e.getX(), e.getY(), 3, 3);
        }
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        mousePressed = false;
        Graphics g = label1.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(color);  
        g.drawOval(e.getX(), e.getY(), 3, 3);
        System.out.println(" Mouse released.");

    }

    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        color = colorChooser.getColor();

    }



}
```

Comment: Have you added your class to the classpath? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class

Answer (score 0):

> run my program in Eclipse

In Eclipse, go to Run -> Run Configurations. Under Main tab: the Main Class defines the class which contains the main method you wish to run. Click the Search button. Eclipse will search for classes that contain a main method from which you can choose to run. From there you can apply or choose to Run directly