# Could not load main method when setting class path

Tags: java, import

I am trying to run a java program in linux server which includes an imported jar.
While compiling it is not giving any issues , but when I try to run, it is giving an error "Error: Could not find or load main class ". If I remove the import and its references , my code is working fine without any load issues.
Any inputs please

```
javac -cp "/opt/CARKaim/sdk/pwdsdk.jar" SamplePwd.java     //No issues
java  -cp "/opt/CARKaim/sdk/pwdsdk.jar" SamplePwd          //Error: Could not find or load main class
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/ first link in the related questions?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `SamplePwd` has an [entry-point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point#Java) (e.g. `main(String[] args)`) make sure the current folder is also in your class-path, like

```
java -cp "/opt/CARKaim/sdk/pwdsdk.jar:." SamplePwd
```