# Could not find or load main class when running through command line

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, command-line, classpath

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class) question on adding dependencies through the command line, I'm unable to launch my application due to the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class kiaragen.class
```

I have tried the variations described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath) question:

```
$ java -cp ".:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/*:kiaragen/lib/*" kiaragen/bin/org/fiware/kiara/generator/kiaragen.class
Error: Could not find or load main class kiaragen.bin.org.fiware.kiara.generator.kiaragen.class
$ java -cp ".:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/*:kiaragen/lib/*" kiaragen/bin/org/fiware/kiara/generator/kiaragen
Error: Could not find or load main class kiaragen.bin.org.fiware.kiara.generator.kiaragen
$ java -cp .:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/*:kiaragen/lib/* kiaragen/bin/org/fiware/kiara/generator/kiaragen.class
Error: Could not find or load main class kiaragen.bin.org.fiware.kiara.generator.kiaragen.class
$ java -cp .:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/*:kiaragen/lib/* kiaragen/bin/org/fiware/kiara/generator/kiaragen
Error: Could not find or load main class kiaragen.bin.org.fiware.kiara.generator.kiaragen
$ java -classpath ".:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/*:kiaragen/lib/*" kiaragen/bin/org/fiware/kiara/generator/kiaragen
Error: Could not find or load main class kiaragen.bin.org.fiware.kiara.generator.kiaragen
$ java -classpath .:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/*:kiaragen/lib/* kiaragen/bin/org/fiware/kiara/generator/kiaragen
Error: Could not find or load main class kiaragen.bin.org.fiware.kiara.generator.kiaragen
```

where **kiaragen** is the root directory of the project(I need to run the **kiaragen.class** from outside that directory). I'm using java 1.8:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

on ubuntu 14.04. The bytecode file **kiaragen.class** exists and does have an entry point. The project has been compiled with IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4.

The dependencies shown in IntelliJ are:

[image: kiaragen_dependencies]

What am I missing?

**Edit #1:**

I've run the following commands:

```
$ java -cp ".:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/*:/home/kiara/AppLab/KIARA/kiaragen/lib/*" kiaragen/bin/org.fiware.kiara.generator.kiaragen
Error: Could not find or load main class kiaragen.bin.org.fiware.kiara.generator.kiaragen
$ java -cp ".:kiaragen/lib/*" kiaragen/bin/org.fiware.kiara.generator.kiaragen
Error: Could not find or load main class kiaragen.bin.org.fiware.kiara.generator.kiaragen
$ java -cp ".:kiaragen/lib/*" kiaragen/bin/org.fiware.kiara.generator.kiaragen
Error: Could not find or load main class kiaragen.bin.org.fiware.kiara.generator.kiaragen
```

**kiaragen.class** is at the specified location:

```
$ find kiaragen/ -name "kiaragen*"
kiaragen/
kiaragen/kiaragen.iml
kiaragen/src/main/java/org/fiware/kiara/generator/kiaragen.java
kiaragen/bin/org/fiware/kiara/generator/kiaragen$TemplateErrorListener.class
kiaragen/bin/org/fiware/kiara/generator/kiaragen.class
kiaragen/scripts/kiaragen.sh
kiaragen/scripts/kiaragen.bat
```

Why can't java find it?

**Edit #2:**

The packages are structured as:

[image: package_tree]

**Edit #3:**

**kiaragen.java** does have a **main()** method:

```
/*
     * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * 
     * Main entry point
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ColorMessage.load();

        m_platforms = new ArrayList<String>();
        m_platforms.add("gradle");

        try {

            kiaragen main = new kiaragen(args);
            if (main.execute()) {
                System.exit(0);
            }

        } catch (BadArgumentException e) {

            System.out.println(ColorMessage.error("BadArgumentException") + e.getMessage());
            printHelp();

        }

        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

Comment: What's the `package` for `kiaragen`? Which `jar` contains this `class`?

Comment: @CKing "kiaragen.src.main.java.org.fiware.kiara.generator.kiaragen.java"

Comment: kiaragen.class is the actual application I want to run. It is not part of a .jar file but depends on those mentioned in the question.

Comment: See my answer and let me know if it works for you. I don't have enough information to point out the exact command to run your class but my answer will point you in the right direction. You have been around for a while so you know this site works. Feedback is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get it running(by copying the run command from IntelliJ):

```
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7534 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/usr/share/intellijidea-ce/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/kiara/AppLab/KIARA/kiaragen/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/home/kiara/AppLab/KIARA/kiaragen/lib/antxr.jar:/home/kiara/AppLab/KIARA/kiaragen/lib/stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar:/home/kiara/AppLab/KIARA/kiaragen/lib/kiaraparser-0.1.0.jar:/home/kiara/AppLab/KIARA/kiaragen/lib/antlr-4.4-complete.jar:/home/kiara/AppLab/KIARA/kiaragen/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/usr/share/intellijidea-ce/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.fiware.kiara.generator.kiaragen
```

To run without IntelliJ:

```
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/bin/java -classpath /home/kiara/AppLab/KIARA/kiaragen/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/home/kiara/AppLab/KIARA/kiaragen/lib/antxr.jar:/home/kiara/AppLab/KIARA/kiaragen/lib/stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar:/home/kiara/AppLab/KIARA/kiaragen/lib/kiaraparser-0.1.0.jar:/home/kiara/AppLab/KIARA/kiaragen/lib/antlr-4.4-complete.jar:/home/kiara/AppLab/KIARA/kiaragen/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/usr/share/intellijidea-ce/lib/idea_rt.jar  org.fiware.kiara.generator.kiaragen
```

Since no sane person wants to input that everytime I created an alias:

```
$ vim ~/.bashrc
alias kiaragen="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/bin/java -classpath /home/kiara/AppLab/KIARA/kiaragen/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/home/kiara/AppLab/KIARA/kiaragen/lib/antxr.jar:/home/kiara/AppLab/KIARA/kiaragen/lib/stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar:/home/kiara/AppLab/KIARA/kiaragen/lib/kiaraparser-0.1.0.jar:/home/kiara/AppLab/KIARA/kiaragen/lib/antlr-4.4-complete.jar:/home/kiara/AppLab/KIARA/kiaragen/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar org.fiware.kiara.generator.kiaragen"
```

save and close and load **.bashrc**.

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: 1) You are still including an IntelliJ IDEA lib in your classpath: `/usr/share/intellijidea-ce/lib/idea_rt.jar`. 2) I am not sure why IntelliJ IDEA chooses to explicitly include the JDK JARs. Another than that, I seems to use a verbose version of the one I suggested in my answer. Did that not work for you?

Comment: @hzpz Thanks for the notice. Removed the entry and it still worked. I've tried your answer and it works as well.

Comment: Don't mention it! If your problem is solved, please accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The way you provide the path to your class in the `java` command is incorrect. But before we get to that, ensure that `kiaragen` has a `public static void main(String []args)` method.

If it does, try the following suggestion :

The fully qualified name of a Java `class` starts with the `package` and ends with the name of the `class`.

Assuming that the package statement in `kiaragen.java` is `package org.fiware.kiara.generator;`, the fully qualified name of this class is `org.fiware.kiara.generator.kiaragen`.

You can run this class from outside the root directory of your project as follows :

```
java -cp ".:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-jdk/jre/lib/*:kiaragen/lib/*" kiaragen/bin/org.fiware.kiara.generator.kiaragen
```

That being said, there is no need to add the `jre/lib` directory to the classpath explicitly unless you have placed some of your user defined `jar` files there.

Comment: I've run all commands with the fully qualified names, even added the full path to the classpath, yet it still can't find kiarage.class. I've edited the question.

Comment: @Sebi It's really not that complex if you understand the basics. I suggest you go through the oracle documentation on `CLASSPATH`.

Comment: I do understand the basics. I do not understand why I java shows the error Error: Could not find or load main class regardless of the input(see the edits).

Comment: @Sebi Well, does `kiaragen.java` have a `public static void main(String []args)` method?

Comment: Yes, it does and it's unique within the project(Edit #3).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to include the path to your class files (in the `bin` directory) in the classpath. Second, since judging from the IntelliJ screenshot src/main/**java** is your source directory (it is marked blue), the fully qualified reference to your main class is `org.fiware.kiara.generator.kiaragen`.

Assuming you are in the parent directory of your program, try running

```
java -cp kiaragen/lib/*:kiaragen/bin org.fiware.kiara.generator.kiaragen
```

Answer (score 0):

To execute the `public static void main(String args[]);` method of class `org.a.b.c.theClass`, which is located at `d/e` subdirectory, you have to execute the following statement:

```
java -cp 'd/e:$CLASSPATH' org.a.b.c.theClass
```

You have to include the directory path that **does not** belong to the package name in the class path, **and the path that belongs** to the package name into the package name, so there must be a class file located at: `d/e/org/a/b/c/theClass` (file must be named `d/e/org/a/b/c/theClass.class`).

For your case, it depends where are you trying to execute your java file from, but supposing you try to execute it from the same place where you executed the `find` command:

```
java -cp "kiaragen/bin:$CLASSPATH" org.fiware.kiara.generator.kiaragen
```

would be the proper command (you have never used absolute paths in your qestion, and no idea where your project directory is, so I used all paths relative to where you issued the `find` command)

So, in case you live at `/home/yourname` and supposing your kiaragen project is at `workspace/kiaragen`, a possible absolute path (allowing you to execute it independent of your current dir) would be:

```
java -cp "/home/yourname/workspace/kiaragen/bin:$CLASSPATH" org.fiware.iara.generator.kiaragen
```

(the `$CLASSPATH` allows you to include the original class path and to find the normal java library classes)