# Java execution error: Could not find or load main class Main

Tags: java, jvm, runtime-error

I have the following directory, let's call it `program/`, housing the following items:

```
Circle.java 
Point.java 
Shape.java
Triangle.java
Main.java
Geometry/`
```

All of the .java files are part of the same `geometry` package, so I use this command to compile them together:

```
javac -d Geometry/ Main.java Triangle.java Shape.java Point.java
```

This puts a `.class` file for each of the above files into the directory `program/Geometry/geometry`. It also puts those same files into the /program directory, so I guess my **first question** is why does it put those `.class` files in both locations? There doesn't seem to be a point in putting them with the `.java` files if they are contained by themselves in the `geometry` package directory.

Regardless of the answer to that, my **main problem** is that I can't seem to get my program to run. Inside `Main.java`, there is the `Main` class with a `main()` function that is supposed to work its magic. I have run the following command in both the `program/` and `program/Geometry/geometry` with the same error, both listed below:

```
java Main 
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here, and give me an answer to my first question as well? Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: You should have googled first for solution. Still have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class

Comment: This is not a compilation error and it does not happen at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a classpath. In the same folder that you ran your compilation above, something like

```
java -cp Geometry Main
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Main.java` file must have *main()* method.

Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
}
```