# Error: Could not find or load main class in eclipse IDE after cleaning project

Tags: java, eclipse

Initially I was getting error for database connectivity as my project was unable to get metadata about database and could not connect to database, I read somewhere to clean project,.. and i tried clean project in eclipse java but after cleaning got following error,.. unable to understand , what to do,  if any one could help,..

Error: Could not find or load main class..

Comment: Do you have a class in your project which contains main method. Also try to clean and build your project once more and see if there are any compilation issues

Comment: [POSSIBLE DUPLICATE] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class)

Comment: does the project has maven nature?

Comment: @Haim, no it doesn't have maven nature

Answer (score 0):

i have faced same Error: Could not find or load main class problem in Eclipse IDE
Solution: Go to Project- generate javadoc- use standared doclet-set the path "C:\Users\Lenovo\workspace\" what is your project path in your system then finish
Before all this unchecked Build Automatically 
then run or run button or run as configurations.
its worked for me....

Answer (score 0):

Providing my solution to the same issue.
Step 1: Clean project.
Step 2: do maven force update.
Step 3: Run the main class again from the class itself.

Note: I did an eclipse restart before step 2. But that is optional.