# Javac CMD compiling Error. Error: Could not find or load main class DungeonGame

Tags: java, compilation, javac

I am not sure why I am getting this error. It even shows when I compile it that I have the class file in the folder but this error happens. I will give my code which is a basic game I made. I am new to Java.

```
package game; 
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.Random;

public class DungeonGame {
public static void main (String[] args){

    // System Objects
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random(); 

    // Game Variables
    String[] enemies = {"Skeleton", "Zombie", "Warrior", "Assassin"}; 
    int maxEnemyHealth = 75; 
    int enemyAttackDamage = 25; 

    // Player Variables
    int health = 100;       // How much health we have
    int attackDamage = 50;  // How much damage our player can do
    int numHealthPotions = 3;  // Number of health pots our player is set with
    int healthPotionHealAmount = 30; // Amount a health the pot will raise
    int healthPotionDropChance = 50; // Percentage drop
    boolean running = true; 
    GAME: 
    while (running) {
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        int enemyHealth = rand.nextInt(maxEnemyHealth); // Get a random health for enemy (How strong is the enemy?)
        String enemy = enemies[rand.nextInt(enemies.length)]; //Set random enemy from array
        System.out.println("\t#" + enemy + "appeared! #\n");
        while(enemyHealth > 0) {
            System.out.println("\tYour HP: " + health);
            System.out.println("\t+" + enemy + "'s HP: " + enemyHealth);
            System.out.println("\n\tWhat would you like to do?");
            System.out.println("\t1. Attack");
            System.out.println("\t2. Drink health potion");
            System.out.println("\t3. Run!");
            String input = in.nextLine(); 
            if(input.equals("1")){
                int damageDealt = rand.nextInt(attackDamage);
                int damageTaken = rand.nextInt(enemyAttackDamage);
                enemyHealth -= damageDealt;
                health -= damageTaken;
                System.out.println("\t> You strike the " + enemy + "for" + damageDealt + "damage."); 
                System.out.println("\t> You recieve" + damageTaken + "in retaliation!"); 
                if(health < 1) {    
                    System.out.println(">t You have taken too much damage, you are to weak to go on!");
                    break; 
                }
            }
            else if (input.equals("2")){
                if(numHealthPotions > 0) {
                    health += healthPotionHealAmount;
                    numHealthPotions--;
                    System.out.println("\t> You drink a health potion, healing yourself for " + healthPotionHealAmount + "."
                                        + "\n\t> You now have" + health + "HP."
                                        + "\n\t> You have" + numHealthPotions + "health potions left.\n"); 
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("\t> You have no health potions left!! Defeat enemies for a chance to get one. \n"); 
                    }
                }
           else if(input.equals("3")){
               System.out.println("\tYou run away from the " + enemy + "!");
               continue GAME; 
            }
            else {  
                System.out.println("\tInvalid Command!");
            }
        }
        if(health < 1) {    
            System.out.println("You limp out of the dungeon, weak from battle.");
            break; 
        }
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(" # " + enemy + " was defeated! #"); 
        System.out.println(" # You have " + health + "HP left. #");
        if(rand.nextInt(100) < healthPotionDropChance) {    
            numHealthPotions++;
            System.out.println(" # The " + enemy + "dropped a health potion! #");
            System.out.println(" # You now have " + numHealthPotions + "health potion(s). # ");
        }
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("What would you like to do now?");
        System.out.println("1. Continue fighting");
        System.out.println("2. Exit game");         
        String input = in.nextLine();
        while(!input.equals("1") && !input.equals("2")) {
            System.out.println("invalid Command!");
            input = in.nextLine(); 
        }
        if(input.equals("1")) { 
            System.out.println("You continue on your adventure!");
        }
        else if (input.equals("2")) {
            System.out.println("You exit the dengeon, successful from your adventures!"); 
            break;
        }
    }           
}
```

}

Comment: You have a lot of code that's unrelated to the error. Please try to isolate the issue in as few lines of code as possible.

Comment: If you are running game from CMD, you propably dont have set your class path. Try something like this `java -classpath pathToYourPackageWithClassFile game.DungeonGame` See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class?rq=1) well answered related question.