# Java compiler doesn't work

Tags: java

I'm trying to launch my java file Test.java like this:

```
java -cp . gcomputing.Test
```

I'm here: `/src`
and my Test.java file is here: `/src/gcomputing/Test.java`

My Test.java file :

```
package gcomputing;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hi");
  }
}
```

The output is:

> Error: Could not find or load main class gcomputing.Test

I already tried those links:

- [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)
- [Error: Could not find or load main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class)

Comment: if your compiler didn't wok, you wouldn't get that error message.

Comment: So it's not my compiler. I knew that, but I don't know while it doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you have this package statement: package sismage.gcomputing; when your package is actually gcomputing ?

Comment: Rather than saying your question isn't a duplicate, how about saying which questions you read, tried, and didn't succeed using.

Comment: @Stultuske my bad, it's not like that in the file. (i putted an other version of my file)

Comment: Did you compile it? you are trying to run it, the compile command is javac, not java

Comment: Maybe try reading the documentation: [Compile and run your first Java program](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/84/compile-and-run-your-first-java-program#t=20160729130805337198).

Comment: Firstly, if you encounter a situation where it is the case that either Java doesn't work or you are using Java incorrectly, it is probably the latter.

Comment: If `sismage` is really not in your source file, then where does it come from? The compiler doesn't make such things up by itself... you probably forgot to save your source file in your editor, or you are compiling a different file than you really think you are compiling.

Comment: I changed the "sismage" thing. It was a mistake.

Comment: How are you compiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found. It's my bad:

the Eclipse "build" created some .class file, and my Test file was in it. But not (why?) at the same place.

Found with the $find linux command.

Thank you and excuse me,

Clément

Comment: "why?" because it's standard practice not to build things in your `src/` tree. It's much easier if you can just blat the build directory by itself, without worrying about source code mixed up with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go to the folder containing your file using cd command.

Then type:

**javac Test.java**

**java Test**

It should run the main method of your program.

Comment: yes, but it seems that's not what he's trying to do. and it should work from a parent folder just as well

Comment: Yes but I can't use javac. Indeed, i'm in a professional computer and the already-implemented version works without it. Maybe, when we do a build in Eclipse it creates the .class files automaticaly?

Answer (score 0):

**java** command is not compiler, it's runtime invocation program. Java compiler is **javac**

The correct invocation of compiler should look as following in your case:

```
$ javac src/gcomputing/Test.java
$ java -cp ./src gcomputing.Test
 Hi
```

You can find more details in [Oracles' documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/compile-136656.html)