# How to compile and run a .java file which is set in a package?

Tags: java, package, javac

The **K.java** file

```
package com.mypackage;
public class K{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello at last!");
  }
}
```

Now I am an Ubuntu user so I open my terminal and try to compile with the **javac** command.

```
javac K.java
```

and it seems to be compiled cause I get a K.class file in the same directory.
The problem is when I am trying to run it with the **java** command.

```
java K
```

I get the following compiler error

> Error: Could not find or load main class K

I also tried to run java com.mypackage.K but I am getting the same error. What am I missing? This should have been very simple right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class/29331827#29331827

Comment: So I have to set somehow the classpath variable pointing to the directory which containis the .class files?

Comment: No, you have to set your classpath to the directory that contains the directory `com` which in turn contains the directory `mypackage` which contains the file `K.class`.