# How to run StanfordCoreNlpDemo.java

Tags: java, classpath, stanford-nlp

I successfully compiled StanfordCoreNlpDemo by running:

```
javac -cp "*" StanfordCoreNlpDemo.java
```

and it compiled successfully. I then tried to run it with:

```
java -cp "*" StanfordCoreNlpDemo
```

I then received the following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class StanfordCoreNlpDemo

I realize this is a CLASSPATH issue so I tried to add the path to the folder:
`/some/path/stanford-corenlp-full-2016-10-31/*`

Nonetheless, I still get the same error. How do I run StanfordCoreNlpDemo.java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem of StanfordCoreNlpDemo program because I ran that code in Netbeans before. The problem seems associated with classpath issue.

Since the `StanfordCoreNlpDemo.java` file belongs to a package

```
package package edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.demo;

public class StanfordCoreNlpDemo {
    public static final void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // code goes here
    } 
}
```

Then calling the following results in `Error: Could not find or load main class TheClassName`.

```
java -cp . StanfordCoreNlpDemo
```

It must be called with its fully-qualified name:

```
java -cp . edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.demo.StanfordCoreNlpDemo
```

And this `edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.demo` directory must exist in the classpath. In this example, `.`, meaning the current directory, is the entirety of classpath. Therefore this particular example must be called from the directory in which `edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.demo` exists.

Reference

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/29331827/5352399
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18093929/5352399