# Execute a java class file that uses class from a jar file

Tags: java, ubuntu, command-line, jar

I have a java source file named `File_2.java` that starts with `import Jama.*;`  and it contains the main method.
The current directory contains java source file `File_2.java` and the **Jama-1.0.3.jar** file

I can compile the source `File_2.java` using

```
javac -classpath Jama-1.0.3.jar File_2.java
```

This generates a **File_2.class** file in the current directory which is not getting executed. I have tried the following

```
$ java File_2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Jama/Matrix
at File_2.main(File_2.java:32)
```

and

```
$ java -classpath Jama-1.0.3.jar File_2
Error: Could not find or load main class File_2
```

Thus my question is how do I execute the **File_2.class** file ? Kindly help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add your current directory to in order to find your class file. 
You must run `java -classpath Jama-1.0.3.jar:. File_2`.

Comment: I am getting `Error: Could not find or load main class :.`

Comment: Are you sure you aren't adding a space after colon? You have to write exactly `java -classpath Jama-1.0.3.jar:. File_2` or `java -cp Jama-1.0.3.jar:. File_2`. The dot after colon is used in order to add your .class file to your classpath.

Comment: It works. There was a space appearing before colon (due to tab completion). Thanks.