# Ant: Add path to a java class inside a bash script

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, ant

I have an ant project in a directory which has 2 directories: `bin` and `src` and two files `build.xml` and `script.sh`.

The `script.sh` has the command:

```
time java SomeTestClass
```

where `SomeTestClass` is a class in `bin`. The bash script is executed in `build.xml` using the following:

```
<target name="run">
    <exec executable="/bin/bash">
            <arg value="script.sh"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

However when I build using `ant` I get an error:

```
[exec] Error: Could not find or load main class SomeTestClass
```

How can I have the bash script see the java class `SomeTestClass`? I tried adding `./bin/SomeTestClass` in the bash script, but the error changed to:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ..bin.SomeTestClass
```

Comment: what happens if you run the script from commandline like `./script.sh` ?

Comment: @NikitaSkvortsov same thing

Answer (score 1):

use this script:

```
 time java -cp bin SomeTestClass
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in calling `SomeTestClass`. Several options here:

1. You must ensure that you add the location of your .class file to your classpath. So, if its in the current folder then add . to your classpath
2. If the class is in a package thepackagename - it must be called with its fully-qualified name:

`java -classpath . thepackagename.TheClassName`
Please, read the fcomplete guide: 
[Error: Could not find or load main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class)