# Could not find or load main class TxtToCsvConverter.data_preprocess

Tags: java, mainclass

The code is like this:

```
public class TxtToCsvConverter{

private static final String DATA_FILE_NAME = "/Desktop/ml-1m/movies.dat";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    StringBuilder bulider = new StringBuilder();

    try{
        // Open the file
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(DATA_FILE_NAME);
        // Create a new csv file to store your data
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("result.csv"));
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(fileInputStream);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataInputStream));
        String strLine;
        // Read file line by line
        while ((strLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] stringArray = strLine.split("::");
            for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
                bulider.append(stringArray[i]);
                bulider.append(",");
            }
            bulider.append("\n");
        }
        // Close the input stream
        dataInputStream.close();
        // Write builder into file
        writer.write(bulider.toString());
        // Save the file
        writer.close();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // Catch exception if any
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

And it appears to come out a error says

> Could not find or load main class TxtToCsvConverter.data_preprocess"

I couldn't find the reason. Please help

Comment: Thousands of answers can be found here: [What does “Could not find or load main class” mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Could not find or load main class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class)