# Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.rocketmq.namesrv.NamesrvStartup

Tags: rocketmq

I setup RocketMQ following the guide of Quick Start https://rocketmq.incubator.apache.org/docs/quick-start/ ,run

```
sh bin/mqnamesrv
```

the logs shows:
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0

Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=320m; support was removed in 8.0

Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: Using the DefNew young collector with the CMS collector is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release

Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release.

Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.rocketmq.namesrv.NamesrvStartup

Comment: Could you please, format your question? It's difficult to read and understand your problem

Comment: POssible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class?rq=1

Comment: Can you find the related rocketmq-namesrv.jar in your `distribution/target/apache-rocketmq`?

Answer (score 0):

I come to the same problem, when I use `rocketmq-4.0.0`.

I unzip the [source zip](https://archive.apache.org/dist/rocketmq/4.0.0-incubating/rocketmq-all-4.0.0-incubating-source-release.zip), and run the mqnamesrv

```
nohup sh bin/mqnamesrv &
```

the problem occurs...

my solution is following:

compile the source with maven-3.6:

```
mvn -Prelease-all -DskipTests clean install -U
```

then cd `target/apache-rocketmq-all`, I repeat the command:

```
nohup sh bin/mqnamesrv &
```

mq runs well.