# How to compile and run a multi-package NetBeans project in terminal

Tags: java, netbeans, terminal

How do I compile and run a NetBeans Project that has multiple packages that contain multiple classes in the terminal?  I get:

```
        Error: Could not find or load main class CharacterCreatorapp.class
```

when trying to compile some of the classes within a package I get:

```
          $ javac Wizard.java
          Wizard.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
          public class Wizard extends CharacterCreator
                        ^
          symbol: class CharacterCreator
          Wizard.java:31: error: method does not override or implement a
          method from a supertype
          @Override
          ^
          Wizard.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
            + super.toString() 
              ^
          symbol:   variable super
          location: class Wizard
          3 errors
```

and this is after CharacterCreator.java compiled successfully.

Comment: go to ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class?rq=1 ) it might help.