# Error: Could not find or load main class while class is included in the jar file

Tags: java, jar

I want to mention that I already read these threads:

[Error: Could not find or load main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

and I found no solution to my problem. 
I have a jar file named BatchPricing.jar that includes a class named com.tools.batchpricing.Main. 
I know this for sure because I open the jar file with 7-zip and I see this class there.

When I run it on windows I activate the command:

> java -Xmx300M -classpath BatchPricing.jar com.tools.batchpricing.Main %*

I run if from the folder that contains BatchPricing.jar. However, I still get the error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   com.tools.batchpricing.Main

Do you know how I can resolve it?

Comment: What does `jar -tf BatchPricing.jar` say?

Comment: Is there, by any chance, a difference between upper and lower case characters in the class name?

Comment: @lexicore, it doesn't show this class. Now I understand that only com.tools.batchpricing.Main.java (without class file) is included in my jar file. Probably I had a compilation error. Thanks. Please add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @CrazySynthax Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should do in this situation is to run:

```
jar -tf my-package.jar
```

This will list files in the JAR, somethink like:

```
org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDatePrinter$Rule.class
org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDatePrinter$StringLiteral.class
org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDatePrinter$TextField.class
org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDatePrinter$TimeZoneDisplayKey.class
org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDatePrinter$TimeZoneNameRule.class
org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDatePrinter$TimeZoneNumberRule.class
org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDatePrinter$TwelveHourField.class
org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDatePrinter$TwentyFourHourField.class
org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDatePrinter$TwoDigitMonthField.class
org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDatePrinter$TwoDigitNumberField.class
```

Make sure you see `com/tools/batchpricing/Main.class` in this list. If your class is not in this list or is included as `com/tools/batchpricing/Main.java` instead of `.class`, probably something went wrong with compilation/building of the JAR.

Comment: @CrazySynthax Concerning your edit: `jar -tf` lists all the files in the JAR archive, not only class files.