# Run Java files does not work in windows command prompt

Tags: java, windows, cmd

I want to run a java file in windows command prompt instead of the IDE. I have a file named Names.java and compiling with `javac Names.java`
works fine. Nevertheless, after compiling this file, I get an Error when I want to run that file with`java Names`. This ist the Error:

```
Error: Could not  find or load main class Names
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: myFiles/Names (wrong name: Names)
```

(FYI: myFiles is the name of my package I created in Eclipse)

Bizarrely, it works fine if I run the .java-file  with `java Names.java` , but I need to run the compiled .class-file.

Comment: The run-source-directly option is new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your project looks like this:

```
  Desktop/
    myFiles/
      Names.java
```

On the shell, you cd to your Desktop folder, and compile the file

```
> javac myFiles/Names.java
```

To run your class, you stay on your Desktop folder, and provide the full name of your class (includes the pacakge name)

```
> java myFiles.Names
```

That should run your `Names.main()` method

Answer (score 0):

use command java Classname in your case you have run command as given below

Java Names

there is not need of .java while running class file

Answer (score 0):

`cd ..`

`java myFiles.Names`

Then it should work.

Also read [Error: Could not find or load main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class#29331827)