# Compile error of base64 in cmd

Tags: java, cmd, base64

I am trying to compile an applet using cmd and I get the following error:

```
Mc.java:1: error: package org.apache.commons.codec.binary does not exist
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
                                  ^
Mc.java:279: error: cannot find symbol
    byte[] accountKeyBytes = Base64.encodeBase64((accountKey + ":" + accountKey).getBytes());
                             ^
symbol:   variable Base64
location: class Mc
2 errors
```

Any idea how to solve the problem?

After the compile with jar files I get that error:

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apach
 e/commons/codec/binary/Base64
    at Mc.SearchApi(Mc.java:279)
    at Mc$ButtonHandler.keyPressed(Mc.java:172)
    at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6463)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2829)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6282)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1895)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:762)
    at   java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1027)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeybo
    ardFocusManager.java:899)...
```

Comment: Apache commons are not on the class path.

Comment: Yes thank you. But when I included in class path like this: javac -g -cp YOUR_JAR.jar YOUR_FILE_NAME.java and then run it java -cp YOUR_JAR.jar; YOUR_MAIN_CLASS. I get error message could not find or load main class MCL.class

Comment: but you had compile errors not runtime soooo.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is library file missing in your porject.
You just need to download apache jar file and set it into your java class path.

```
commons-codec-x.x.jar
```

If you still doubt at jar file set into class path, you can find out with below links.
[Adding jar to classpath when running from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385148/adding-jar-to-classpath-when-running-from-command-line) 
[Including jars in classpath on commandline (javac or apt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096283/including-jars-in-classpath-on-commandline-javac-or-apt)

Comment: Yes, I have download the commons-codec-1.10.jar but I get this error again

Comment: correctly set its to class path?? and compile time is still error??

Comment: I compile with this command:javac -g -cp commons-codec-1.10.jar;jsoup-1.8.1.jar Mc.java but it is applet and I used the appletviewer Mc.html to run it. Is it correct?

Comment: Why you don't use some IDE for compile and run.It's more easy and great.I would recommend you to use Eclipse IDE.

Comment: In the compilers run perfectly but I want to include this applet in web application so I need to run in cmd as well.

Comment: After add library, your error is still same your title question.?Can you provide your full source code for more help??

Comment: Sorry I get the error again for the libraries I will post piece of code for more help

Comment: can you look the code above and the error message. I will appreciate!

Comment: your error is can't find your commons-code.xxx.jar file from your main class.You should try first how to set jar file to classpath from command line.Because this additional answer should not post under your topic I think.

Answer (score 0):

Windows:

For the latest JDK 1.8. version

You can add the jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\ext

It worked for me. I didn't use any IDE just wrote in notepad and compiled in command prompt.