# java cassandra connection java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster

Tags: java, maven, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am trying to connect to Cassandra with datastax driver. 
So far I have just tried to run the SimpleClient app available in tutorials but I am having troubles.

Here is the Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster
    at com.cass.App.connect(App.java:17)
    at com.cass.App.main(App.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 2 more
```

Here is my maven file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.cass</groupId>
  <artifactId>Connector</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Connector</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.25.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>18.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.yammer.metrics</groupId>
    <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
  <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>
<build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is my java file

```
package com.cass;

import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Host;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Metadata;

/**
 * Generate a unique number
 *
 */
public class App 
{

    private Cluster cluster;

public void connect(String node) {
      cluster = Cluster.builder()
            .addContactPoint(node).build();
      Metadata metadata = cluster.getMetadata();
      System.out.printf("Connected to cluster: %s\n", 
            metadata.getClusterName());
      for ( Host host : metadata.getAllHosts() ) {
         System.out.printf("Datatacenter: %s; Host: %s; Rack: %s\n",
               host.getDatacenter(), host.getAddress(), host.getRack());
      }
   }

   public void close() {
      cluster.close();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      App client = new App();
      client.connect("127.0.0.1");
      client.close();
   }
}
```

I am new to both Maven and Cassandra.

**Edit** - it was a stupid mistake of not including snapshot with dependencies in the cp
`java -cp target/CassandraTest2-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.Test.App`

Comment: how are you running it..

Comment: java -cp target/Connector-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.cass.App

Comment: did you solve it ? I had a similar problem. Could you update the question in case you solved? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ok the issue is that **the required jar is not present in classpath** or when you are running from command prompt, it is not able to locate those jars.

Separator `;` is for `windows`. On `Unix systems` you should use `:`

please follow these two links, similar issues with answers.

```
java -cp jar1:jar2:jar3:dir1:. MyProgram
```

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385148/adding-jar-to-classpath-when-running-from-command-line) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096283/including-jars-in-classpath-on-commandline-javac-or-apt)

Comment: Wouldn't maven handle the dependencies?

Comment: @pJAEY Maven will download the jars and dependent jars, but you need to referenced it in your classpath.

Comment: I'd recommend looking into the maven assembly plugin and [jar-with-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies) to build a jar that includes all dependencies.   Another option is to use maven itself to run your main class using the [exec:java](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html) goal to run your main class.

Comment: Didn't change anything.
I fixed it by trying
`java -cp target/CassandraTest2-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.Test.App`

Comment: Good catch on the classpaths @ankur-singhal. thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Only difference was datastax version was 2.1.1. Later i realized this version has an issue. My project started working after changing the version from 2.1.1 to 2.1.9 (In fact I tested your version too. it was working. Other that this version, it worked on all others. Strang!)

And for the maven. Yes, it does handle the dependency. Normally, if you put the dependency in pom file and run the class it handles. It did for me too.