# Error- TestngTestSuiteUsingXML.java:6: error: package org.testng does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testng, command-prompt

1. I have a Project called **OneReports** In Eclipse. In the Project i have a Package called **Test**.
2. The Project as follows:[image]
3. while running the ** TestngTestSuiteUsingXML** java file in eclipse it is fetching the **Test.XML** and it is working fine.

But when i verified the same in command Prompt getting error as follows:

```
C:\Jars>javac TestngTestSuiteUsingXML.java
TestngTestSuiteUsingXML.java:6: error: package org.testng does not exist
import org.testng.TestNG;
^

TestngTestSuiteUsingXML.java:7: error: package org.testng.xml does not exist
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
^
TestngTestSuiteUsingXML.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
^
symbol: class XmlSuite
location: class TestngTestSuiteUsingXML
TestngTestSuiteUsingXML.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
^
symbol: class XmlSuite
location: class TestngTestSuiteUsingXML
TestngTestSuiteUsingXML.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
^
symbol: class XmlSuite
location: class TestngTestSuiteUsingXML
TestngTestSuiteUsingXML.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
^
symbol: class XmlSuite
location: class TestngTestSuiteUsingXML
TestngTestSuiteUsingXML.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
TestNG tng = new TestNG();
^
symbol: class TestNG
location: class TestngTestSuiteUsingXML
TestngTestSuiteUsingXML.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
TestNG tng = new TestNG();
^
symbol: class TestNG
location: class TestngTestSuiteUsingXML
8 errors
```

Comment: Could anyone please help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add testNG.jar to the classpath. The following links might be helpful :-

[Java command line with external .jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069702/java-command-line-with-external-jar)

[How to include jar files with java file and compile in command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395207/how-to-include-jar-files-with-java-file-and-compile-in-command-prompt)

You would have to download testNG jar and add it as well as selenium jar files to your class path.
I suggest you to use a build and dependency tools such as maven or ant