# How to create a package directory in Java

Tags: java, package

I am extremely new in Java and I couldn't get one thing straight. I have E:\Java\ACP\Cricket\ directory where I have a Main.java, Player.java and CricPlayer.java. Now I am inheriting `Player` class into `CricPlayer`.
I have Main.Java as

```
import Java.ACP.Cricket.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello.");
    }
}
```

CricPlayer.java As...

```
import Java.ACP.Cricket
public class CricPlayer extends Player
{
}
```

I need to use objects of `CricPlayer` in Main.java. As I mentioned earlier I am real new to Java so there might be some really obvious mistakes that I don't know about. But the question is how can I create a package for use in CricPlayer.java and Main.java? Because each time I compile the code using CMD it says "CricPlayer.java:6: error';' expected import java.ACP.Cricket.*" and points ^ to *. I don't know if I haven't created the Package properly or if it's some syntactical issue.

Comment: Are the jar files located in E:\Java\ACP\Cricket folder because if the  jars are not located their you need to link them in the compiler.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069702/java-command-line-with-external-jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add package declaration in the beginning of your code files. And you don't need imports if all the classes reside in the same package. BTW, good coding convention in java recommends that all letters in package name are lowercase :)

```
package Java.ACP.Cricket;
public class Main
{
// Your class contents
}
```

Comment: Ok now I got that error removed but the compiler is now saying that it can not find symbol "Player" in  CricPlayer.java.

Comment: Also when I compile javac Player.java it doesn't create Player.class in the directory although there are no errors during the compilation.
@Kristjan Veskimäe

Comment: Go in your command prompt into root catalog E:\ and compile 'javac Java/ACP/Cricket/Player.java' and should be fine. BTW you only need to compile the class that uses other classes, those dependant classes will be compiled automagically.

Comment: I tried that but the compiler still doesn't know about the CricPlayer or Player Identifier in the code
I have written in the code
package Java.ACP.Cricket.CricPlayer;

public class Main
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  System.out.println("Hello");
  CricPlayer obj;
 }
}
and the compiler says the package Java.ACP.Cricket doesn't exist! Also it declare CricPlayer to be undeclared, I believe it to be because of the package.

Comment: A little new to stackoverflow forgot to tag you. :)

Answer (score 0):

in the class below you shourd write a package (folder in project where file is situated)
for example
**package ACP.Cricket;**

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `;` at your import in CricPlayer class:

```
import Java.ACP.Cricket.*;
```

Now you should be able to create CricPlayer Objects in your Main Class.

Answer (score 0):

Also I don't know if "Java" in your package name is supposed to be capitalized or not. Seems like the compiler is expecting a lower case 'J' from your naming convention

Answer (score 0):

Vincenzzochi is right, packages are lower case (but it should not break compilation).
And you need to declare the package at the begining of all your classes : 
package java.acp.cricket;

And while all your source files are in the same package, you don't have to import anything!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative to your Programs.I've verified this myself, so you can be assured that it will work.

Important thing you need to know, is that any file can be compiled only if you have a main method for that file(ie in that class). so here's a detailed 'How to do it':

PlayerDemo.java:

```
package Java.ACP.Cricket;
class Player{
//class members & methods
}
class PlayerDemo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Player Class");
    }
}
```

CricPlayerDemo.java:

```
package Java.ACP.Cricket;
class CricPlayer extends Player{
// class members & methods
}
class CricPlayerDemo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("CricPlayer Class");
    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
package Java.ACP.Cricket;
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Main Class");
//use other class objects here directly.
    }
}
```

In E: , do following stepwise:

```
1> javac PlayerDemo.java (this creates Player.class & PlayerDemo.class)
2> copy Player.class to Cricket folder.
3> javac CricPlayerDemo.java (this creates CricPlayer.class & CricPlayerDemo.class)
4> copy CricPlayer.class to Cricket folder.
5> javac Main.java 
6> copy Main.class to Cricket folder.
7> now,also in E:, java Java/ACP/Cricket/Main
```

Instead of compiling from E:, you can also compile from Cricket,to avoid copying class files,but it wont work for CricPlayerDemo.java, as CricPlayer extends Player(whose location is acc to package) so you'll have to compile CricPlayerDemo from E: