# Classpath Wildcards - Class Not Found Java

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

While running a scheduler program through command prompt, I am getting the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/quartz/ScheduleBu
ilder
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.quartz.ScheduleBuilder
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: ScheduleEmail.  Program will exit.
```

Even after adding all the jar files also I am getting the following.

Java command : `java - cp .;E:/Jars/*; ScheduleEmail`

Can anyone please suggest why I am getting this?

Comment: as far as I know wildcards do not work in classpath. You need to specify jar files directly.

Comment: You can't use wildcards in your classpath, you need to specify each and every Jar file...individually :)

Comment: But I took this as a consideration , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069702/java-command-line-with-external-jar

Comment: E:/Jars/* doesnot add all your jars to classpath. Either add them manually of create a script to build the full jar names based class path string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a wildcard (on windows platform), you need to surround it with quotes to work correctly:

```
java -cp ".;E:/Jars/*;" ScheduleEmail
```

<sub>1. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html</sub>

Answer (score 0):

first, make sure if there is a typo, there's no space between "-" and "cp"
second, check if quarts jars are in E:/Jars/

Comment: by having a typo in between - and cp you would have a different type of error