# package javax.media does not exist

Tags: java

I am working on an audio player and need to add `pause()` and `play()` features in it to connect with `JButtons`. The problem is I am not able to import Media package as it says package does not exist. I cannot find anywhere it online to download the package. Same goes for `AudioPlayer` class which gives bad class file error.

Comment: Can you post the full name of the package you're trying to use?  Is this part of an external library / jar file?  Are you using any build tools like ant, maven, or gradle?

Comment: Next time use findJar: http://findjar.com/index.x?query=javax.media 
It is a very useful site for this kind of search.

Answer (score 1):

you need the JMF libraries , you can get them from there , for windows there is a typic installer :

[JMF Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-142937.html)

Comment: i have it downloaded but still i am not able to use AudioPlayer class in my code.

Comment: which IDE are you using ? have you import the external jar in the project's build path??

Comment: my teacher restricts me to use cmd for compiling while the code is written in notepad++. i didnt get second part of your question

Comment: so you test the code in cmd , like java -jar Test.jar

Comment: well i dont remember for sure the command that youll have to use , but you ll have to define the jmf.jar path in order to be able to compile / run the app. There are some examples to compile / run a java project with external jars , check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069702/java-command-line-with-external-jar

Answer (score 1):

It is a late answer, but you can use the Maven dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.media/jmf -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmf</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1e</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question,

You can down load [java.media](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#7372-jmf-2.1.1e-oth-JPR)

then use

```
 import javax.media.*;
```

then you can declare like

```
Player  audioplayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(file.toURI().toURL());
```

And

`audioplayer.start();` and  `audioplayer.stop();`

Here `file` means where the source file saved.

NB: you can use JMF jar file

Try like this

```
try {
                audioplayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(file.toURI().toURL());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MY_MP3_PLAYER.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (NoPlayerException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MY_MP3_PLAYER.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (CannotRealizeException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MY_MP3_PLAYER.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

OR Try the sample code given below

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.media.CannotRealizeException;
import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.NoPlayerException;
import javax.media.Player;

public class Mp3Player {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoPlayerException, CannotRealizeException {

    // Source  of song file
    File f=new File("your path in which mp3 file is saved");
    // Create a Player object that realizes the audio
     final Player p=Manager.createRealizedPlayer(f.toURI().toURL());

    // Start the music
      p.start();


   // Create a Scanner object for taking input from cmd
         Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);


   // Read a line and store it in st
         String st=s.nextLine();


   // If user types 's', stop the audio
   if(st.equals("s"))
   {
    p.stop();
   }
   }

 }
```

Comment: anywhere i can get AudioPlayer class? it provides predefined play() pause() methods.

Comment: go to the link in answer download JMF api.  The class AudioPlayer  has play() and stop () method. just use like in answer

Comment: when i write that Manager.createRealizedPlayer() line.. it gives me error that javax.media.Player cannot be converted to Player

Comment: its working code, if its not working for you, check your jar file and path

Comment: It compiles fine. It gives runtime error
Exception in thread "main" javax.media.NoPlayerException
and if i place a try-catch for the code.. it gives runtime error java.io.IOException: file not found

Comment: File f=new File("your path");edit with path where you saved your mp3 file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80172/discussion-between-anptk-and-masu).

Answer (score -1):

Following four packages will solve your problem. They contains most of helpful methods to deal with audio player.

```
import javazoom.jl.decoder.JavaLayerException;
import javazoom.jl.player.AudioDevice;
import javazoom.jl.player.FactoryRegistry;
import javazoom.jl.player.advanced.AdvancedPlayer;
```

You can use .stop(), start(), .play() etc. from above packages.
Hope that will help.

Comment: thank you :)
if you could tell me what is "jl" because i'll be having viva for this.
would this let me make objects of Player, AudioPlayer?
I also want a pause feature. would this allow me?

Comment: now it gives me error that these packages do not exist

Comment: Weel, it is not included in the default SDK, download it from [JavaZoom](http://www.javazoom.net).

Comment: They are packages created to manage audio/video behavior on java. while, decoder, player etc. are folders inside the package. further down in the hierarchy, audiodevice, factoryregistry, advancedplayer, javalayerexception etc. are subfolders in those folders. Get the understanding of hierarchy in java packages.

Comment: and for your error solution, try to import whole package instead of those particular folders. use import javazoom.jl.*; and remove all four imports from the code

Comment: and yes, as suggested by MouseEvent, if import doesn't work then download the package from JavaZoom (link: http://www.javazoom.net/projects.html)