# Android/Java: how to import javax.media.j3d?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opengl-es

I want to use [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/java3d/forDevelopers/J3D_1_3_API/j3dapi/javax/media/j3d/Texture2D.html) Texture2D class.

I don't see how to download the package javax.media.j3d (or javax.media) in order to use it in my Android Studio project.

Any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [package javax.media does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692366/package-javax-media-does-not-exist)

Comment: No. The JMF lib mentioned on this page by @Anptk contains a media package but not the one I want (javax.media.j3d). I don't where and how to download it...

Comment: Right. I did a bit more research. The Java3D API has not been part of Java SE for a while. Looks like [these guys](https://jogamp.org/) are continuing the effort. Consider that the documentation you've linked is from Java 1.3 (released 20 years ago), so some things may not work in the same way.

Comment: Thanks Federico but I don't see on this website where I can find my package ; do you have a more specific link ? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I found it here ! https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php?title=Downloading_and_installing_Java3D Thanks !!!