# How to include external jar files into a java project without an IDE?

Tags: java, classpath

I do have a project that depends on external libraries (jfoenix is one of them). I didn't want to add the libraries  using IDEs like Eclipse, Netbeans or any other IDE. The Directory structure looks like,

Project Folder:MyProject

Package :afa

Where and how should I include the external jar files and compile my classes which are inside the package? I found answers that say, put your jar files in the classpath or -classpath  but I need a step by step guide on how I can do this. All my java classes are in the same package.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069702/java-command-line-with-external-jar is the first thing that shows up when you search for "java external jars". Maybe check it out?

Comment: Use Maven to build your app. You probably don't want to do the low-level calls to `javac -cp ...`  and `java -cp ...`